# How to configure connection pool in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling

How to configure my Spring Boot service to have max 2 open connections to the Postgres database? Application is used on the PRODUCTION only by a few people and I don't want to

my pom:

```
(...)
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
            <artifactId>hessian</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
       (...)
    </build>

</project>
```

and my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=2 //I think it is not sufficient
```

info.app.name: xxx

I think spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=2 is not sufficient. What should I add to the properties file? Should I maybe exclude HikariCP from my pom file?

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring Boot 2.0, **Hikari** is the default `DataSource` implementation. Therefore, if you want to configure the `maximumPoolSize` (a parameter for [Hikeri Configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby)) in Spring Boot, you are supposed to set it as follows:

**For application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
```

**For application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 2
```

Comment: And it is sufficient? Nothing more?

Comment: @Matley YES! I think it is sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: How do we verify this? I've made the change but I still see that my configuration component in spring boot is spinning up 8 times

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed the connection implementation pool that Spring is using, it should be HikariCP, and then the setting you're looking for is:
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size

its listed here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html